# MS SSIS : Data Type conflict for variables (String vs Object) working with Access MEMO type

Tags: ms-access, ssis

I made this package to make my sql task more dynamic:
Step1.  I select SQLtext to run from my AccessTable and store in SQLStr var.

Step2.  I run that Select statement stored in var SQLStr from Step1.
However I can run Step1 only if I used DataType = Object,  and I can run Step2 only if i use DataTYpe = String, I played with it and verified this 100$.
How  I can solve this problem, can I do some convert? of datatypes, my query stored in Access DB type = Memo, as it quite long, and might have line breaks. 
What is the trick ??  Please refer to pic below for all details.

** Please note that this problem only occurs for Access Memo Type field !!!!**
**In other setup it should work with String type OK in Step1**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your first query, when you select `SQLText`, Cast it as a string (in the select statement) so that you can store it in a string variable.

If it is not possible to CAST the memo field to a string in the SELECT (I'm not familiar with Access), then you can iterate through the object variable in a `foreach loop` and store the value of the `SQLText` column in a string variable, and then proceed to step 2 using that.

IF neither of those work, as a brute force method, you can follow the solution in [this thread](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1534163-391-1.aspx) to import the Access table to a Staging table on SQL Server that uses an nvarchar(max) field, which you should be able to select into a string variable with no problem.

Comment: Tx again and sorry it's worked in in TSQL ,but it doesn't work with Access, I did more testing and narrowed it down 100%.  Should be something special about Access Memo --> to String conversion,    CStr doesn't work for SSIS, it still want only object. I'm doing more research how to solve this.

Comment: Just talked to MS gurus, it's known problem about Memo fields in Access db, not talking about conversion it inside SSIS, recommended use Text type if psssble, or use TSL table. In my case SQL command = 2000b, so I'll do something else

Comment: Well the brute force method in the third paragraph should work according to the linked article.

Comment: Yes, Thanks again Tab!!  I have just couple of SQLText entry so it will be easy to create this in TSQL, no problem, at least now I can sleep good!!